# How can I install a keyboard layout on a locked-down workstation?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, dvorak, security-policy

I want to use the Dvorak keyboard layout at work (I already do at home) but I often need umlauts so the built-in US Dvorak isn't enough, and punching in the umlauts' Alt-codes gets tedious really fast.

It's a corporate Win7 computer with security policies that forbid installing files in system32. All keyboard software I've found needs to write to system32, and I don't think the security people would grant me an exception for this.

**Are there any keyboard solutions that can be installed under these limitations?**

Alternatively, I've looked at physical keyboards like the [Typematrix 2030](http://typematrix.com) but they are also "just" keyboards and don't have any internal remapping. They don't appear to Windows as a normal layout while presenting Dvorak to me -- and even if they did, it would be US Dvorak, so again missing the umlauts. I've only found the [FingerWorks TouchStream](http://fingerfans.dreamhosters.com) to be capable of that feat, but it's very different from a regular keyboard.

Comment: Is there a Dvorak-like layout that includes umlauts?

Comment: @techturtle: Windows only exactly 1 Dvorak layout: "US Dvorak". The "US Int'l" layout only exists in Qwerty. There are any number of customized layouts but as mentioned, policies prevent me from installing them.

Comment: As use of a Dvorak keyboard has benefits in reducing RSI, you might be able to approach it as a "medical accommodation" and get the security policies overruled, particularly if all that has to be installed is a keymap file. (No actual security risk, just the time it takes the IT department to deploy it to your PC). I know under US law employers have to provide "reasonable accommodations" for medical conditions and disabilities, I imagine other countries have similar laws. Worth a shot anyway.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, @Stephanie. I would expect that some form of documentation is needed though, you can't just claim it "on a whim."

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run external executables (downloaded or brought in on USB), you can use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/download/) to create your own custom remapping script.  AutoHotKey can be installed (which may or may not require system32 access) or it can be run as a standalone/portable version.  You can also compile your script into its own executable file.

Using AutoHotKey, you can make your own custom version of Dvorak (by remapping all the keys on the keyboard), or you can use the US-Dvorak layout provided with Windows and just use AutoHotKey to add in your own shortcuts for the umlauts and other special characters, preventing the need to type them out with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> codes.